# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation " - " does not exist

Tags: python, django

(New to Django) - I am looking to create two model with a foreign key. The first model is called `Portfolio`, and each Portfolio has many member through the second model `Portfoliomember`.
It currently looks like this:

```
class Portfolio(models.Model):
    portfolio_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.portfolio_name

    class Meta:
        db_table = "portfolio"

class PortfolioMember(models.Model):
    portfolio = models.ForeignKey(Portfolio, related_name = "portfoliomember", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quality =  models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.portfolio


    class Meta:
        db_table = "portfoliomember"
```

Later i aim at using formset in a form. but for now, when i try to create the migration, i get the following :

```
Running migrations:
  Applying app.0019_auto_20210318_1544...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\FrankyDoul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "portfoliomember" does not exist

django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "portfoliomember" does not exist
```

Is there an obvious reason why this would not work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you define in your Meta class db_table? I don't know what is your app name but normally you don't need to do that except for specific reason. See this (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/options/) " Django automatically derives the name of the database table from the name of your model class and the app that contains it".

So when you define db_table = 'another_name', you override the database table name. I would suggest to remove this line i.e. db_table = "portfoliomember" and see if the error persist.

Comment: Hi Gilles, thanks a lot . It doesn't look like that is the problem.

Comment: Did you do a python3 manage.py makemigrations before migrate? If you have an error it means that you have a problem with your database.

Comment: Merci mais avez vous trouvé le problème?

Comment: Salut, oui c est bon, alors en bas de la Class PortfolioMember, au lieu de "return self.portfolio", il faut mettre "return self.portfolio_id" avec le "_id". Parce que la foreign key rajoute _id  a la variable apparemment. Vous m'avez mis dans la bonne direction.